# how to handle a filtered value in input with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-forms

In AngularJS, which is the best way to handle a filtered value in an input?

Our user should input a number and see it localized, but you cannot bind an input to a model and format it with a filter.

We could have a separate formatted input and parse it, but maybe there's a more elegant way.

Anybody has a better idea?

HTML:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = {
        'val': 12.34
    };              
};
</script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form> 
      <input type="text" value="{{test.val|number:1}}" ng-model="test.val" />
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/monguz/6u0zqc0L/

We are using AngularJS 1.4, localized in italian

Thanks a lot

Marco

Comment: Have you considered using validation? http://jsfiddle.net/6u0zqc0L/13/

Comment: thanks wbeange, but our user should input a number with a comma as decimal separator